# why is sql server doing nested loops

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested-loops

I have 2 tables facts and customer, with 422,000 and 350,000 rows.

When running this query, the joining used is Hash Match:

```
SELECT SUM(sales), [state], County
FROM pp.Facts f
INNER JOIN pp.Customer c ON (c.customerKey = f.customerKey)
WHERE c.County IN (N'Nassau', N'Westchester', N'Erie', N'Orange', N'Union', 
                   N'Santa Clara', N'San Diego', N'Essex', N'Morris', 
                   N'Dallas', N'Allegheny', N'Bucks')
GROUP BY [state], County
```

And it works great.

When running is query (same, but with more items in the filter), the joining changes to Nested Loops and never comes back (obviously)

```
SELECT SUM(sales), [state], County
FROM pp.Facts f
INNER JOIN pp.Customer c ON (c.customerKey = f.customerKey)
WHERE c.County IN (N'Nassau', N'Westchester', N'Erie', N'Orange', N'Union', 
                   N'Santa Clara', N'San Diego', N'Essex', N'Morris', 
                   N'Dallas', N'Allegheny', N'Bucks', N'New York', 
                   N'Bergen', N'Montgomery', N'Harris', N'Delaware', N'San 
                   Francisco', N'Suffolk', N'Travis', N'Middlesex', 
                   N'Bexar', N'Tarrant', N'Los Angeles', N'Philadelphia')
GROUP BY [state], County
```

Why is the joining method changed?

There is a FK defined on the customerKey columns and a PK on customer.customerKey (no additional indexes)

Comment: Q: Why has the plan changed?  A: The queries are different.  Seriously though, the optimizer will use statistics to estimate the number of rows returned from each operator in the execution plan.  Have a look at the `Estimated Number of Rows` returned from the Customer table.

Comment: May be because in the first query the county filters 10% customers and in the second one it filters a larger percentage of records e.g. 30%.

Comment: @MJH the "Estimated Number of Rows" was 1 for the customer tables, so the optimized thought there will be 1 go for the nested loops... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why?  That is simple.  When SQL Server is analyzing the query during the compilation phase, the optimizer considers different execution plans.  Apparently, the optimizer thinks that the nested-loop is more efficient than other methods.

The optimizer is wrong, probably because statistics are not correct or because assumptions about value distributions are not true for your query.

I have faced this problem in the past with views -- where small changes to underlying data caused big changes to query plans.  I recommend that you use query hints to ensure that you get the plan you want, probably:

```
OPTION (HASH JOIN)
```

For this query:

```
SELECT SUM(f.sales), c.[state], c.County
FROM pp.Facts f INNER JOIN
     pp.Customer c
     ON c.customerKey = f.customerKey
WHERE c.County IN ( . . . )
GROUP BY c.[state], c.County;
```

You want indexes on `Customer(County, State, CustomerKey)` and `Facts(customerKey, sales)`.  The index is a covering index.  The first column should satisfy the `WHERE` clause.

I notice that you are using `nvarchar` constants.  This assumes that `c.County` is `nvarchar`.  If it is `varchar`, drop the `N`.

Comment: The proposed index for Customer looks very strange.

Comment: In the suggested index, `State` could be moved to end, or even `INCLUDE`d. I might as well create a reverse index `(CustomerKey, County) INCLUDE (State)` let SQL server choose (and delete the one not chosen).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server chooses the plan in terms of resources.
The type of connection (LOOP | MERGE | HASH) is selected based on the estimated number of rows and order.
If you do not have indexes, dbms can be bad in calculating the result of rows and, under "more" number of conditions, assume a much smaller number of lines and, as a result, build a plan with NL.
Try creating statistics on the (customerKey, Country), NC index. Or use hints INNER HASH JOIN or the entire query OPTION (HASH JOIN). But if conditions change, you can get a bad plan using hints.